# "English proficiency" vs "proficiency in the English language"

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, difference, grammaticality-in-context

What is the difference between these sentences?

- Reading will improve people's English proficiency.

AND

- Reading will improve people's proficiency in the English language.

Comment: What do you think the difference is?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between these sentences?

They mean basically the same thing.

"proficiency in the English language" seems to be the more "proper" and "complete" way to say it. People will certainly understand both sentences.

> Any other comments?

The word "people" is very general. If the text is aimed at the reader, you could say "your". If the text is aimed at teachers, then "the student's".
The word "English" is very specific. Since the comment applies to all languages, you could possibly use the word "language" instead: "Reading improves language proficiency." "Reading will improve your proficiency in the language".